# Selecting specific keys from a PHP array and then comparing them

Tags: php, arrays

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this.

Essentially what I am trying to do is, for each "ticketX" array, select the first response (by date) and then the first response from the helpdesk. So with the example below I would expect the following to be returned:

**Ticket 1**

Key "2" and date "2013-11-22 16:35:51"
Key "1" and date "2013-11-22 16:51:15"

**Ticket 2**

Key "5" and date "2013-11-22 14:41:27"
Key "3" and date "2013-11-22 15:47:02"

I guess the next logical thing would be to put these results into another separate array which I can then compare? The ultimate goal here is to calculate the response time of the helpdesk, from the customer's first post, to the reply of the helpdesk.

I'm not sure how to even approach the issue, so I'm pretty stuck. I could probably hash something together, but I would much rather seek guidance first!

At the moment I just have this:

```
foreach($tickets AS $key => $value) {
    if(count($value) > 1) {
        foreach($value AS $value2) {
            echo = $value2['created'];
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the array:

```
Array
(
    [ticket1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 17:03:31
                    [author] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 16:51:15
                    [author] => helpdesk
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 16:35:51
                    [author] => 1
                )

        )

    [ticket2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 16:48:17
                    [author] => helpdesk
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 16:20:18
                    [author] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 15:49:16
                    [author] => helpdesk
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 15:47:02
                    [author] => helpdesk
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 15:44:57
                    [author] => 2
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [created] => 2013-11-22 14:41:27
                    [author] => 1
                )

        )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to track from the moment the incident was created, to the first action by helpdesk.

If so, you want to capture the first entry in the array, and the first helpdesk entry in the array.

Some code reminiscent of this should work

```
$first = true;
$result = array();
foreach($tickets AS $key => $value) {
//    if(count($value) > 1) {
        foreach($value AS $value2) {
            if($first){
                 $result[$key]['created'] = $value2['created'];
                 $first = false;
            }else if('helpdesk' == $value2['author']){
                 $result[$key]['responded'] = $value2['created'];
                 break;
            }
        }
//    }  If check here is not actually required
}
```

That will give you the two variables you need to make your calculation for each ticket.  You should be able to use php's date() and strtotime() functions to reach the rest of your goal.

Comment: Thanks Joel! The only issue is that it gives you the last reply, rather than the first. Is there an easy way to fix that? For example it returns the "0" keys, when I really want "2" and "5".

Comment: Fixed it myself using $lastKey = end($value);

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.  I also did a slight modification and removed if(count($value) > 1).  If $value is an empty array, you can still pass it to a foreach loop (it will loop 0 times) without error.  The only time you'll get an error is if $value isn't an array at all.  And even then, the count($value) would return an error anyhow.